# How to include dynamic strings in json file?

Tags: json

I have a json file as shown below

```
[
  {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "custom",
      "html": "<button id='changecolor' style='color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: white; border-color: rgb(158, 50, 168);'>Accept</button>"
  }
]
```

Instead of the background-color - white for the button , I want have a dynamic variable there. How can I achieve it.

Comment: Json is the serialisation of an object. It's like snapshoot of the object properties and values. A "dynamic property" make little sense here. I will recommend reading [ask]. I think we are missing the context to understand what you are really trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply cannot be achived by using a json file. Instead you can use a function that returns this json object. So you can pass the color as argument to the function, and which can be included in the json object.

```
var getData = (color)=>{

    var data = {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "custom",
        "html": `<button id='changecolor' style='color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: ${color}; border-color: rgb(158, 50, 168);'>Accept</button>`
    }

    return data
}
```

later you can call getData(color) at the place you use the json object.

You can also save this as a js file if needed

```
export const data = color => ({
            "id": 0,
            "name": "custom",
            "html": `<button id='changecolor' style='color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: ${color}; border-color: rgb(158, 50, 168);'>Accept</button>`
        })
```